# Connecting to MySQL-database

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a WWW-page in www.freehostingcloud.com. I created a database of the name sample. But how can I connect to it in MySQL and PHP? I saw from PHP.net that I should type

```
mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

OK, so my_db=sample but what are those parameters 'localhost', 'my_user' and 'my_password'?

Comment: do you ever access your db using a MySQLWorkbench or SQLyog or terminal or something?  i could tell you where to find all of it there

Comment: I have used only phpMyAdmin but now I found a terminal on it.

Comment: should be just as good but im not familiar, ill try to read up quick for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the host, username and password required to access your database. Localhost means your computer aka `127.0.0.1`, the others are the users you create in your local db.

Comment: i don't see how you could possibly describe that any simpler :)

Comment: OK but how do I know who will use my database, as just anyone can register to my page via Internet.

Comment: when you created your database, you should have made a root login. with this root login you should create regular users.

Answer (score 0):

They are documented in the *Parameters* section of [`mysqli::__construct()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php).